# Spring MVC REST JsonSerializer serialize long in exponential notation format

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jsonserializer

There is custom Json serializer(for ObjectMapper) in my Spring MVC REST application:

```
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate>
{

    public LocalDateSerializer()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            jgen.writeNumber(value.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis());

        }
    }
}
```

and service returns json representation of this field **with exponential notation format**  e.g.  1.377216E12 instead of normal timestamp format.**And this happens not for all server platforms.**

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add this System.out.println(Locale.getDefault()); to the different servers, what do you get? I suspect you have different locales on your servers and this produces the different number formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the number like this:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%d", value.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis())
```

This will use exactly that pattern.

Comment: But I need to write long? not a string - jgen.writeNumber()

Comment: Ahh... stupid of me. Sorry. Still, I think that your problem is with locale. Se my comment above.